# Svelte route gives me 404

Tags: javascript, user-interface, routes, svelte

I created a simple router for my app in Svelte.
It is working if I'm accessing the link from the nav bar.
If I reload the page, it give me 404.. why ?

```
<Router url="{url}">
 <nav>
   <Link to="/">Home</Link>
   <Link to="charts">About</Link>
 </nav>
 <div>
  <Route path="charts" component="{About}" />
  <Route path="/"><Home /></Route>
 </div>
</Router>
```

After reload:
This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:5000/charts

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You must make sure your server is serving the `index.html` for every route path and not just for `/`.

If you e.g. are using `sirv` with one of the Svelte starter projects you can add the `--single` flag to the script.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "sirv public --single",
  "start:dev": "sirv public --dev --single"
},
```

Comment: Is there a solution when rollup is involved?

Comment: @LSR I think that rollup will call npm run start when it finishes building, so a config like this should work:
```"scripts": {dev": "rollup -c -w", "start": "sirv public --single"}```

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in one of the comments above, if using roll-up, the following combination of scripts will work when calling `npm run dev`

```js
"scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public --single"
  }
```

Comment: Anyone who's using rollup, the above modifications to script works.

Answer (score 3):

This is for those who want to host the svelte apps, If your hosting provider supports
adding redirect or rewrite rules then you can do this to serve the `index.html` for any request you make which the router can handle.

For example,
Set source as `/*` the `/` refers to the path and the wildcard `*` refers to match arbitrary request paths.

and then set your destination to just `/` that's it. don't set the destination as `/index.html` or else all requests will open your home page for example if you try to open `www.example.com/about` then it will open `www.example.com/index.html`

and set the action as `Rewrite` instead of `Redirect`

and this also solves the problem of refreshing the site and opening the URL directly from browswer

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
"start": "sirv public  --no-clear"
```

To this

```
"start": "sirv public -s --no-clear"
```

in your `package.json` file, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we won't be able to access your link as it is a local link only accessible from your local machine.

However my bet would be a redirection issue. You are trying to access the `chart` file on your server, that arguably doesn't exists as your router is supposed to do that job.

You need to configure your server so that every route is redirected to your index file, and then the router will be able to do it's job by analyzing the url.