# How to return the svelte app for all URLs?

Tags: node.js, svelte

The app works when I request `'/'`, but when I request `'/foo'` I get a 404 error.

How can I return the app for all routes?

Comment: I don't think we can understand your question or be able to help you without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: There's no relevant code. This is the default behaviour that you get with a new svelte app.

Comment: What you need to do is redirect all routes to the `/`. [This](https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing/issues/58) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57339349/9434800) might help.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do this in development by adding the `--single` flag to the `start` command, but I still don't know how to deploy it like that.

Answer (score 2):

Svelte is not a web server. A Svelte project compiles into an HTML page and associated JS and CSS bundles, that's it.

If you want to handle all routes and redirect to the root of your app (`/`) then you have to either configure whatever web server you are operating (Apache, nginx, ...) to do that for you, or you have to set up a back end (Node + Express, for example) that will handle a catch-all 'wildcard' route and either redirect to the root route or serve your Svelte page right-away (if you plan on using a router client-side, for example).

Some hosting services like Surge, Now (oops, Tercel), Heroku, etc. might also allow you to configure your project to automatically redirect to the root path or serve content from a catch-all route.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling to reach the same goal as the OP. Given the lack of documentation in Svelte, here is the solution I came to and which works for a deployment on `Surge`.

`Surge` [documentation on routing](https://surge.sh/help/adding-a-200-page-for-client-side-routing) made me understand I needed a `200.html` file to be able to handle properly routing on client-side. Though, I still needed a `index.html` file to handle the app on localhost. I finally came up to using [rollup-plugin-copy](https://github.com/vladshcherbin/rollup-plugin-copy) to perform a copy of `index.html` to a `200.html` page during the build phase, so that `Surge` has that page to handle the routing as expected.

Relevant code in `rollup.config.js`:

```js
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy'

export default {
  
  plugins: [
    ...
    copy({
      targets: [
        { src: 'public/index.html', dest: 'public', rename: '200.html' }
      ]
    })
  ]
}
```

Note that the compiled file goes to `public` directory. If you have your file compiled to another directory (for example `dist`), please adapt the code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you deploy it.  The functionality that serves '/' as a certain component exists in the web server software.  The '--start' works with the dev server apparently.

If you're using sapper, it should work if you do 'npm start'.  If you're just serving the single-page index.html some other way, do searches for `deploy spa` or `routing index.html` along with whatever server software it is being deployed to (i.e. `deploy spa apache`).

It also depends on what routing you're using if you want to intercept that path and do anything with it.  I'm not sure how to do it [with sapper], maybe define a default slug?  Other routing libraries will have their own way.  Generally you define a route '*' that is a catch-all and pick what component you want to render when the url doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

On plain PHP serwer like apache. I think that making directory with name of route and PHP file inside it with redirection to specific HTML svelte file would make a job.